# For 或, what semantic notions underlie "tool or weapon on a pole" (戈) + "mouth" (口) + "territory" (1)?

Tags: etymology

I consulted p 399,  [*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary) that It substantiates Wiktionary's definitions. I can't access the ["slightly revised through July 2005" ed.](https://wenlin.com/abc%22)

[image]

How did [戈 + 口 + 1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%88%96#Glyph_origin) compound to mean

> 1. or; either ... or ... (used to list alternatives)

> 2. perhaps; maybe (mostly found in news headlines)?

> 3. occasionally; sometimes

Please answer separately for each of the 3 meanings. [CUHK](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%96) doesn't expound. I quote [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?zi=%E6%88%96#) for completeness.

> **Synopsis  :** 甲骨文象有納柲的「管銎斧」或「柲帽」之形，是一種兵器。後來柲形與「[◎](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E2%97%8E)」分離，可能是變形音化，以「[◎](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E2%97%8E)」（「[員](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%93%A1)」的初文）作為「[或](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%96)」的聲符。
>
> **Elaboration:** 甲骨文象有納柲的「管銎斧」或「柲帽」（參見下面的「其他圖片」）之形，是一種兵器。（李學勤、謝明文）商代晚期的金文與甲骨文同，後來柲形與「[◎](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E2%97%8E)」分離。謝明文認為「[◎](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E2%97%8E)」的脫落可能是變形音化，以「[◎](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E2%97%8E)」（「[員](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%93%A1)」的初文）作為「[或](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%96)」的聲符。「[◎](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E2%97%8E)」的周圍或加上飾筆，「[柲](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%9F%B2)」形又演變為象「[戈](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%88)」形，為《說文》小篆所本。後來的人根據訛變的字體，又誤把疆域、國家之類的假借當作「[或](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%96)」的本義或引申義，於是把「[或](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%96)」附會成一個會意字，故《說文》云：「或，邦也。从囗从戈，以守一。一，地也。」
>
> 「[或](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%96)」在甲金文中多用為人名、國名或族名。如《合集》4268：「乙亥卜，永鼎（貞）：令或來歸。」季老或盉：「季老或乍（作）文考大白（伯）□□。」
>
> 「[或](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%96)」也假借作副詞，訓為「[再](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%86%8D)」、「[又](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8F%88)」。如《屯南》2991+620+2291「其或幼（？）盂田」，「[幼](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%B9%BC)」是和祭祀有關的動詞，全句意謂在盂地之農田再一次舉行幼祭。（謝明文）[妾子]壺：「或[目又]（得）[户臣貝]（賢）[左犬]（佐）司馬賈。」
>
> 「[或](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%96)」還表示區域、疆域。如《輯佚》690+《合集》36182：「遇（?）夷方率伐東或。」表示遭逢夷方率兵攻伐東土。又如㝬鐘：「㝬其萬年，畯保四或。」黃金貴指出西周金文的「[或](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%96)」都讀為「[域](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%9F%9F)」。大西克也進一步認為春秋金文乃至郭店楚簡、楚帛書等資料中的「[或](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E6%88%96)」、「[䧕](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E4%A7%95)」、「宀或」等都應讀為「[域](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%9F%9F)」，表示地域、領域，而不是表示國家。如《上博竹書一．緇衣》簡7：「亖（四）或（域）川（順）之。」《郭店簡．緇衣》簡12作「四方[川心]（順）之」。「四或」和「四方」都泛指天下。

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a misunderstanding on the Wiktionary description, which shouldn't have inappropriately linked 口 and 一; these are listed for their *shapes* rather than their *functions*. The description

> Ideogrammic compound (會意): 戈 + 口 + 一, “territory”.

means the separate parts which look like 戈 + 口 + 一 are combined together into one glyph to mean *territory*. The two meaningful components to take note of are [「戈」 (*picture*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=127) *of a* [*dagger-axe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger-axe)) and [「囗」](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/39498/18338) or [「丁」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/jiaguwen?kaiOrder=3) (*picture of fortifications surrounding a settlement*).

*Territory* is now written with the derivatives

- 「國」 (*region, country*), through the addition of another semantic 「囗」
- 「域」 (*territory, region*), through the addition of semantic 「土」 (*earth, soil*)

---

<kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image: 或]
或作父癸方鼎
[集成2133](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2133&jgwfl=)</kbd>

「或」 was originally a compound of 「戈」 (*dagger-axe*, representing military power) guarding 「囗」 or 「丁」 (*picture of fortifications surrounding a settlement*; see [Characters' original forms that have no independent usage](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/39495/characters-original-forms-that-have-no-independent-usage) for further discussion). The original idea was basically that of a *defended settlement*.

<kbd>西周
金
[image: 或]
保卣
[集成5415](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=5415&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
金
[image: 或]
尊
[集成6014](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=6014&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
金
[image: 或]
禹鼎
[集成2833](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2833&jgwfl=)</kbd>

Some variants added strokes surrounding 「囗」 or 「丁」, emphasising the region's boundaries. Compare [「疆」 (originally *field boundaries* (畕)](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=4936), with lines added surrounding the fields later) or 「畫」 (*to draw the line between fields* (田), now written 「劃」).

---

Early on, 「或」 became used for a phonetic loan meaning *someone, something*. The meaning *either, or* is a semantic extension of this phonetic loan meaning. [Schuessler](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:About_Chinese/references#S) suggests that this meaning of 「或」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*[ɢ]ʷˤək/**) is etymologically related to 「有」 (**/*[ɢ]ʷəʔ/**, *there is, exists*). The other senses are either further semantic extensions or from compound words like

- 或許 (*maybe*)
- 間或 (*occassionally, sometimes*)